# Show The Unique Rows In Table One Compared to Table Two on LAMP Stack

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Task:

Find the unique rows from table one. For example, given the following tables:

guests_1.csv

```
firstname,lastname
Alex,Anderson
Billy,Bobson
Casandra,Crowford
Dennis,Dixson
```

guests_2.csv

```
firstname,lastname
Alex,Anderson
Billy,Bobson
Cindy,Crowford
Dave,Dixson
```

I would want: Casandra,Crowford and Dennis,Dixson to be the result since they are unique to table one.

index.php

```
<?php
class DataComparison {
  public function __construct() {
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "root";
    $dbname = "scotchbox";

    $this->conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($this->conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
  }

  public function drop_tables( $tables ) {
    foreach( $tables as $key => $table_name ) {
      $sql = "DROP TABLE $table_name";
      $this->conn->query($sql);
    }
  }


  public function create_table( $table_name ) {
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
    )";

    if ($this->conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Table $table_name created successfully.\n";
    } else {
        echo "Error creating table: " . $this->conn->error . "\n";
    }
  }

  public function load_data( $table_name ) {
    $sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/www/public/" . $table_name . ".csv'
           INTO TABLE $table_name
           FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
           LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
           IGNORE 1 LINES
           (firstname, lastname);";

    if ($this->conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
       echo "Imported CSV data into Table $table_name.\n";
    } else {
       echo "Error importing data: " . $this->conn->error . "\n";
    }
  }

  public function compare_tables( $table_one, $table_two ) {
    $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM $table_one
            LEFT OUTER JOIN $table_two ON ($table_one.id = $table_two.id)";

    $res = $this->conn->query($sql);

    echo '<pre>';

    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
      var_dump($row);
    }
  }
}

$instance = new DataComparison();

$instance->drop_tables( [ "guests_1", "guests_2" ] );

$instance->create_table( "guests_1" );
$instance->load_data( "guests_1" );

$instance->create_table( "guests_2" );
$instance->load_data( "guests_2" );

$instance->compare_tables( "guests_1", "guests_2" );
?>
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. git clone https://github.com/scotch-io/scotch-box import-csv
2. cd import-csv
3. vagrant up
4. then visit: http://192.168.33.10 to check it's working
5. edit import-csv/public/index.php so it looks like the above code segment
6. create guests_1.csv and add the data from above
7. create guests_2.csv and add the data from above
8. then visit: http://192.168.33.10

But the output is just

```
      array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["firstname"]=>
    string(4) "Alex"
    ["lastname"]=>
    string(8) "Anderson"
  }
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["firstname"]=>
    string(5) "Billy"
    ["lastname"]=>
    string(6) "Bobson"
  }
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["firstname"]=>
    string(5) "Cindy"
    ["lastname"]=>
    string(8) "Crowford"
  }
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["firstname"]=>
    string(4) "Dave"
    ["lastname"]=>
    string(6) "Dixson"
  }
```

Which is just the output of table two.

Comment: Did you check tables in DB, are they filled with correct data?

Comment: And with `AUTO_INCREMENT` primary key I bet there will be __no rows__ where id is NULL.

Comment: yes table are filled with correct data, u_mulder I see what you mean, but I'm unsure what the SQL is to compare two tables like the ones created from my data

Comment: Remove `WHERE $table_two.id IS NULL;`

Comment: ok, thank you, that has outputted something now, but it's not what I want, I'll edit the question to better explain my desired end-result

Comment: `FROM $table_one, $table_two`

Comment: Use `SELECT DISTINCT (id), col2, col3 WHERE ...`

Answer (score 0):

A left join will return all the results from table 1 and any from table 2 which match your condition. The important part here is rows in table 2 which don't match your condition will return `NULL`

So the condition you check for is firstname and lastname both match, then you only return the results which are `NULL` as they didn't match.

```
SELECT a.firstname, a.lastname
FROM Table1 a
LEFT JOIN Table2 b ON a.lastname = b.lastname AND a.firstname = b.firstname
WHERE b.lastname IS NULL;
```